# Show that there exists an element $a≠e$, the identity in $g$, such that $a^2 = e$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is **finite group** show that **for each $a$**
, there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $a^n = e$.

---

Somewhere it explained as following :

Consider the set $A =  \{a, a^2, a^3,....\}$.

Since $a\in G, a.a =a^2, a.a.a =a^3, a^4,...\text{etc also} \in G $.

Thus $A \subset G$. It is also given that $G$ is finite group, the element of $A$ should be finite, which implies that elements in $A$ repeat ( otherwise the set will be infinite, which is not possible ).

Hence for some $a^i \in A$, we must have

$$a^r = a^i (r>1)$$

$$\implies a^r.a^{-i} = a^i.a^{-i}$$

$$\implies a^{r-i} = a^{i-i} = a^0 = e$$

Hence, $a^n = e$, where $r-i = n$.

---

My questions are:

1. Above theorem is applicable for abelian group only(due to **for each $a$** ), need not be for group.
2. If I ask a proof for this theorem "If $G$ is a group of **even order**(Is it finite? ), then show that **there exists an element $a≠e$**, the identity in $g$, such that $a^2 = e$. "

Comment: 1. It is valid for any finite group, whether it is abelian or not. 2. "$G$ has even order" implies that $G$ is finite. Are you asking for a proof of the theorem stated in 2?

Comment: @Mithlesh Upadhyay: Do you wanna have a infinite group in which the argument is valid there?

Comment: @Bungo, Yes, I need a proof for 2.  May I have $r-i = 2$?

Comment: @BabakS., well, I consider "Even order implies finite" given in answer by E.Lim. , For, the infinite group, I don't know, genuinely.

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay: The group $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})$ is an infinite group in which the orders of each element of it is of forms $p^k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above is valid for any group. Powers of one element $a$ always commute in any group.

Even order implies finite order (recall that "order of a group" means $|G|$, the number of elements in the group), so yes, such a group is finite and the previous applies.

Suppose $G$ has $2n$ elements. For any $G$ is divided naturally into groups $\{x, x^{-1}\}$, $x \in G$, which has two elements iff $x \neq x^{-1}$ and one iff $x = x^{-1}$. Also these sets are disjoint. There is at least one group of one element namely $\{e\}$. So it cannot be the case that the remaining $2n-1$ elements of $G\setminus\{e\}$ are all divived into groups of 2, so there is at least another group of one, so at least one element that equals its own inverse, i.e. an element such that $x^2 = e$.

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.

Answer (score 3):

1) The above proof works for all groups, not just abelian ones.

2) Even order implies finite. Hint: Split $G$ into sets of the form $\{a, a^{-1}\}$.

Comment: Rt, but $G(a,a^{-1})$ is even order, have we identity element too in the group?

Comment: I need a proof for 2. May I have $r−i=2$?

Comment: It is of even order unless $a = a^{-1}$. This also applies to the identity element.

Comment: (1)The set $ f(a)=\{a,a^{-1}\}$ has exactly two members iff $a$ is not its own inverse. (2) $f(a)\cap f(b)\ne \phi$  iff $f(a)=f(b).$ So the collection of all $a$ such that $a\ne a^{-1}$, together with $e$, has an odd number of members. Some $b$ is left out, and we have $e\ne b=b^{-1}$.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.